# How can I make a bootstrap sidebar, fixed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sidebar

I have been trying to figure out how to make this sidebar fixed, so it doesn't scroll with the main page. I already tried "position: fixed", but that didn't work.
https://www.bootply.com/128936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

**Add on your CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar { position: fixed; }
}
```

**On your HTML, add at main col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-2.**

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-2 main">
</div>
```